# Similar Windows scale on HTML

Tags: html, scale

I am trying to obtain a scale item similar to the one from Windows [image: example].

However everything I search on the web only refers to scaling divs, images, etc.

What I want is this scale and everytime I move it the value changes.

Does anyone have any idea how can achieve this?

Comment: `<input type="range" />`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jwwjxuLt/

Comment: They are called range sliders. Check here for examples on multiple different types and advanced features: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html

Comment: This should get you moving in the right direction - https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<input type="range">` which now has a wide support (http://caniuse.com/#search=range).

The use of this is as follows:
You need to specify a range of values from min to max like this:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100">
```

Also, I strongly recomend you to write the value with javascript if you want the user to get exact values. And, if this is for zooming purposes, you can even define a step attribute, so that, for example it goes in intervals of 25.

Edit: if you need a wider support (ie8 and 9 mostly), you'd need to use other tool like jquery ui or to make your own slide.